# Как растянуть дочерний блок за пределы родительского? Продолжение эпопеи

Tags: css, css3

Добрый день!
Начало истории [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/742569/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как дочерний блок `.wrp` растянуть на всю ширину экрана так, чтобы он выходил за пределы своего родителя `.wrapper`? Где у меня ошибка?
 Спасибо!
p.s.смотреть, что получается, на экранах более 1113px в ширину.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: burlywood;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1113px
  padding: 0 213px 0 0;
}
.wrp {
  background-color: chocolate;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 calc(8px - 50vw) 0 calc(108px - 50vw);
  padding: 0;
  width: calc(100vw - 16px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста
<div class="wrp">Этот блок нужно растянуть по ширине экрана, за пределы его родителя</div>
много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста
</div>
```

Comment: Установите ему `position:absolute` и манипулируйте шириной как угодно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. нужна точка с запятой после `width: 1113px`
2. чтобы на узких экранах не было горизонтальной прокрутки, можно, например, поменять, `width: 1113px;` на `max-width: 1113px;`
3. на экранах с шириной до `1113px` дочернему блоку нужны одни свойства, а потом- другие, поэтому добавляем медиа-запрос
4. слагаемые в `calc` не упрощаю, чтобы было понятнее, откуда они берутся

Вместо `555px` пробовал `556.5px` как половину от `1113px`, но появляется прокрутка. Это пока не знаю, почему.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: burlywood;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1113px;
  padding: 0 213px 0 0;
}
.wrp {
  background-color: chocolate;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 calc(8px + 555px + 213px - 50vw) 0 calc(8px + 555px - 50vw);
  padding: 0;
  width: calc(100vw - 16px);
}

@media (max-width: 1113px) {
  .wrp {
    margin: 0 -213px 0 0;
    width: calc(100% + 213px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста
<div class="wrp">Этот блок нужно растянуть по ширине экрана, за пределы его родителя</div>
много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста много текста
</div>
```